# copying numbers with text c++

Tags: c++, cpu-word, copying

So I have data inside a txt file and I open the txt file then look through it for the keyword I provided
after that keyword it contains numbers like 9203 the numbers change constantly.
So I want to know how would I be able to copy the numbers without knowing what they are exactly if this makes sense.

```
std::fstream iData;
std::string collect;
std::string Value = "Value=";

outfile.open("retrieveData.txt", std::ios::in);
if (outfile.is_open())
{
    unsigned int found = 0;
    while (getline(outfile, collect))
    {
        if (collect.find(Value) != std::string::npos)
            ++found;
    }
    std::cout << "the word was found\n";
    std::cout << "attempting to copy to new txt file\n";
    iData.open("itemValue.txt", std::ios::out);
    iData << Value;
    iData.close();
    std::cout << "Success\n";
}
```

So after Value= string theirs numbers and I want to be able to copy those numbers too as the numbers change on a daily basis I cant input specific numbers

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking about.  Did you perhaps write out a pointer value into the text file?  Is there some code you can share?

Comment: You will need to impove your question. Can you add some example file conent to better understand you might be asking?

Comment: yes give me a sec

Comment: Alright check now I editted

Comment: All that the shown code does is save a single "Value=" text into the output file. The shown code does demonstrate that you know how to use `std::string`s, and its various methods, as well as reading and writing files. This is all the knowledge that's needed to implement this, so it's unclear exactly what your question is.

Comment: Yea I just reread It i did this so wrong brb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is done in a scope and you don't mind have an empty file created if no data matching is found then this would be an approach. Both files are closed automatically on exit of the scope they are defined  in.

```cpp
{
   std::ifstream outfile("retrieveData.txt");
   std::ofstream iData("itemValue.txt");
   std::string collect;
   std::string const Value = "Value=";

   while(std::getline(outfile, collect))
   {
      if(collect.find(Value) != std::string::npos)
      {
         std::cout << "the word was found\n";
         std::cout << "attempting to copy to new txt file\n";
         if(iData << collect)
         {
            std::cout << "Success\n";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Alright this helped me understand the mistakes and correct them so my question is, In the text file retrieveData.txt theirs a string of text called "Value=" after that value= theirs a value for e.g. "Value=50" with other text surrounding it. e.g. "brown items This is Spoon value= 5,000 Quantity 4 silver object og: item, " I want to copy the "value=5,000" only and the value of the item changes on a daily basis so how would I copy the "value=" string with the digits that follow it sense putting specific digits wouldn't be very efficient as the value would be different another day.

Comment: Try: ```using namespace std::string_view_literals;
      constexpr auto Value = "Value="sv;
      if(auto pos = collect.find(Value); pos != std::string::npos)
      {
         collect.erase(0, pos);
         collect.erase(collect.find_first_not_of("0123456789 ,"sv, Value.size()));
         collect.erase(std::remove(collect.begin(), collect.end(), ' '), collect.end());
         iData << collect;
      }
```